# Team Foundation Server autobuild a label

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using TFS 2012 (Express) and MSDEV 2010.

Our code is setup, from using Source Safe, such that the UAT build is implemented as a label on the DEV code.  We would like to keep the same systems now we are using TFS and run an autobuild on both the latest version of the code (currently working) and the label which we have set in the code.

I assumed that it would be the option 'Get Version' in the Advanced settings of the build queue dialog but this does not seem to be the case.

Is this still possible in TFS?

Comment: Get Version was right - I needed to prefix the label with the letter 'L'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Lmylabel in 'Get Version' as described in [versionspec documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or you might create a new build definition and specify it under <kbd>Process</kbd>-><kbd>Advanced</kbd>-><kbd>Get Version</kbd>